# how to get the all attributes that belongs to a attribute group in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have an attribute group and I want to get the list of attributes that belongs a particular attribute group. Is there any way to get all of the attributes under an attribute group?

Answer (score 5):

Works on Mage 1.7.0.0:

```
function printGroupAttributes($groupId) {
    $attributesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
        $attributesCollection->setAttributeGroupFilter($groupId);
        foreach ($attributesCollection as $attribute) {
           echo $attribute->getAttributeCode()."<br/>"; // I launch it from browser
        }
}
$attributeGroupId = 534; // Fill with yours
printGroupAttributes($attributeGroupId);
```

Source: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Group->hasConfigurableAttributes()`