# Get all attributes assigned to attribute group

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I'm working on a import module for magento. I need to find out if a attribute belongs to an attribute group. I have the attribute loaded, as well as the attribute group. I've tried:

```
$attributeCollection = $attributeGroup->getAttributes();
```

The theory was that i could look at the collection, and determine whether or not the attribute has been assigned to the attribute group.

Comment: I think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898607/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the group id from the attribute, and load the group if reqiured.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(ID_HERE);
foreach($product->getAttributes() as $attribute)
{
    $groupId = $attribute->getAttributeGroupId();
}
```

If you then want to load the group model:

```
$group = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')->load($groupId);
```

Comment: This does not work for me as I have the groupId and need to know what attributes are assigned to it.

Comment: That's simple then, inside the foreach you would just do this:

if($attribute->getAttributeGroupId() == GROUP_ID) ..

There's probably a better way to do it using SQL/Collections etc though