# Get products Values and Names from Group Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have this code that I found on another post that it is supposed to get the group's attributes.

```
  <?php function printGroupAttributes($groupId) {
$attributesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
    $attributesCollection->setAttributeGroupFilter($groupId);
    foreach ($attributesCollection as $attribute) {
       echo $attribute->getAttributeCode()."<br/>"; // I launch it from browser
    }
  }
  $attributeGroupId = 224; // Fill with yours
  printGroupAttributes($attributeGroupId);
  ?>
```

Unfortunatelly this gives me only the group's ids. What should I enter on this code so I can get Names and Values also?

Thank you

Comment: It's impossible to answer you without more code...

Comment: This is the code that generates the attribute group id. It does not have something else. It works as it is but it generates just the id and not names and values. Here is the post I found this code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898607/how-to-get-the-all-attributes-that-belongs-to-a-attribute-group-in-magento

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-all-attributes-attribute-name-value-of-a-product/

Comment: This loads names and values from products id's and not from attribute group

Comment: please post print_r($attribute->getAttributeCode());

Comment: under printGroupAttributes($attributeGroupId); or somewhere else? Under printGroup it does not change anything. I appreciate your help

Comment: if I leave it by itself it shows me an error Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on a non-object in...